# How to make Ubuntu stop offering to upgrade from 20.04.5 to 22.04.1?

Tags: apt

I have installed (fresh) Ubuntu 20.04.5 on a laptop.  It keeps offering to upgrade to 22.04.1 (downgrade?!) from the initial install through all subsequent updates.  Obviously it should not be doing this.

[image: Version Contradiction]

What's going on and how to I fix it?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? It seems to be un LTS upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04...

Comment: Well, this is dumb.  I'm not sure how I was continually reading that as 22.04.5.  I'm lame!  Thanks.

Comment: Your misreading aside, there's literally a _Don't Upgrade_ button on your screenshot

Comment: You can switch it off in the Software & Updates program.

Answer (score 9):

**Ubuntu is not offering you a downgrade.**

20.04 was released in April **2020**. 20.04.5 is the same version of Ubuntu with updated kernel and drivers.

Ubuntu 22.04 was released in April **2022**. It is **not** a downgrade, and this behavior it's expected.

To disable the upgrade prompt, you can open the update manager and disable checking for new releases.

However, since it is not a downgrade as you had thought, you can consider upgrading.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to work as intended, no fix requirered.

To disable the release upgrade prompt, edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file from 'Prompt=lts' to 'Prompt=never'.

Comment: Insufficient, you also need `sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd` and to `echo ENABLED=0 | sudo dd of=/etc/default/motd-news` to disable all this phoning home…

Comment: @mirabilos You should read the question again. It is about offering to upgrade to 22.04.1, and nothing else.

Comment: @mirabilos "sudo dd of=" what a crazy way to add a line! ;) read about ">" and ">>"

Comment: @Yura `>` and `>>` are evaluated by the shell, not the command-to-be-run, and therefore cannot write to `root`-owned files. (I’m the developer of a shell, I should know ☻)

Answer (score 4):

The solution (for me) is to more carefully read version numbers.  I was misreading 20.04.5 as 22.04.5 and thus all the confusion.  Thanks to everyone for very patiently explaining things I already know well.  You are all too kind.

Comment: You're not alone, I googled for it, loaded this page, and realized I had read it wrong as well. 

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo sed -i 's/lts$/never/g' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

- The file to edit is `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`
- `sed -i 's/lts$/never/g'` is the command that replaces "lts" with "never" in the aforementioned file, which will give you the result you're wanting
- `sudo` is necessary because your user doesn't own the file you need to change